# Error trying to generate a controller in aspnet core 3 using codegenerator

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am starting a new project in **asp net core 3.1.1**, using a **MYSQL** database. I was able to scaffolding the models using the following command

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=localhost;User=root;Password=123456;Database=proyecto;TreatTinyAsBoolean=true;" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -o Models
```

But when I try to generate any controller using the aspnet-codegenerator it generates the following error: Option 'data server' not supported.

```
Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the model and DbContext: 'Contacto'
Option 'data server' not supported. StackTrace:
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringOption.GetOptionForKey(String key) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs:line 435
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String key, Object value) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs:line 345
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs:line 18
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySqlDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseMySql(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 mySqlOptionsAction)
   at Lcore.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__4_0(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`2.<AddDbContextPool>b__0(IServiceProvider _, DbContextOptionsBuilder ob)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`2.<AddDbContextPool>b__0(IServiceProvider sp, DbContextOptionsBuilder ob)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateDbContextOptions[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<AddCoreServices>b__0(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
Option 'data server' not supported.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__10`1.<AddCoreServices>b__10_1(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetServices[T](IServiceProvider provider)      
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextTypes()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextType(String name)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.DbContextActivator.CreateInstance(Type contextType, Assembly startupAssembly, IOperationReportHandler reportHandler)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkModelProcessor.TryCreateContextUsingAppCode(Type dbContextType, Type startupType)

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
```

The command Im using to generate the controller is the follows

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator  controller -name ContactosController  -dc LCoreContext -outDir Controllers -actions -m Contacto -f
```

This is my **DbContext**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using Lcore.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


namespace Lcore.Data
{
    public partial class LCoreContext : DbContext
    {
        public LCoreContext()
        {
        }

        public LCoreContext(DbContextOptions<LCoreContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Comprobante> Comprobante { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Contacto> Contacto { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ContactoImagen> ContactoImagen { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Domicilio> Domicilio { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EntidadFiscalContacto> EntidadFiscalContacto { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<EntidadFiscal> EntidadFiscal { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Localidad> Localidad { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SituacionTributaria> SituacionTributaria { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TipoIdentificacion> TipoIdentificacion { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Usuarios> Usuarios { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                // optionsBuilder.UseMySql("treattinyasboolean=true", x => x.ServerVersion("10.3.14-mariadb"));
                optionsBuilder.UseMySql(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LCoreConnection"].ConnectionString + "treattinyasboolean=true; " , x => x.ServerVersion("10.3.14-mariadb"));
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Comprobante>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("comprobantes");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.LocalidadId)
                    .HasName("IDX_18EDF3E967707C89");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasColumnName("id")
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)");

                entity.Property(e => e.Acronimo)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnName("acronimo")
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(8)")
                    .HasCharSet("utf8mb4")
                    .HasCollation("utf8mb4_unicode_ci");

                entity.Property(e => e.Activo).HasColumnName("activo");

                entity.Property(e => e.Discrimina).HasColumnName("discrimina");

                entity.Property(e => e.FechaCreado)
                    .HasColumnName("fecha_creado")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.FechaEditado)
                    .HasColumnName("fecha_editado")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.LocalidadId)
                    .HasColumnName("localidad_id")
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)");

                entity.Property(e => e.Nombre)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnName("nombre")
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(64)")
                    .HasCharSet("utf8mb4")
                    .HasCollation("utf8mb4_unicode_ci");

                entity.Property(e => e.Nota)
                    .HasColumnName("nota")
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(124)")
                    .HasCharSet("utf8mb4")
                    .HasCollation("utf8mb4_unicode_ci");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Localidad)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Comprobante)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.LocalidadId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_18EDF3E967707C89");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Contacto>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("contactos");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.ImagenId)
                    .HasName("UNIQ_3446F2C5763C8AA7")
                    .IsUnique();

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.LocalidadId)
                    .HasName("IDX_3446F2C567707C89");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.TipoIdentificacionId)
                    .HasName("IDX_3446F2C565478DC6");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasColumnName("id")
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)");

                entity.Property(e => e.Activo).HasColumnName("activo");

                entity.Property(e => e.Apellidos)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnName("apellidos")
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(64)")
                    .HasCharSet("utf8mb4")
                    .HasCollation("utf8mb4_unicode_ci");

                entity.Property(e => e.FechaCreado)
                    .HasColumnName("fecha_creado")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.FechaEditado)
                    .HasColumnName("fecha_editado")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.FechaNacimiento)
                    .HasColumnName("fecha_nacimiento")
                    .HasColumnType("date");

                entity.Property(e => e.Genero)
                    .HasColumnName("genero")
                    .HasColumnType("smallint(6)");

                entity.Property(e => e.ImagenId)
                    .HasColumnName("imagen_id")
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)");

                entity.Property(e => e.LocalidadId)
                    .HasColumnName("localidad_id")
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)");

                entity.Property(e => e.Nombres)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnName("nombres")
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(64)")
                    .HasCharSet("utf8mb4")
                    .HasCollation("utf8mb4_unicode_ci");

                entity.Property(e => e.Nota)
                    .HasColumnName("nota")
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(124)")
                    .HasCharSet("utf8mb4")
                    .HasCollation("utf8mb4_unicode_ci");

                entity.Property(e => e.NumeroIdentificacion)
                    .HasColumnName("numero_identificacion")
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)");

                entity.Property(e => e.TipoIdentificacionId)
                    .HasColumnName("tipo_identificacion_id")
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Imagen)
                    .WithOne(p => p.Contacto)
                    .HasForeignKey<Contacto>(d => d.ImagenId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_3446F2C5763C8AA7");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Localidad)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Contacto)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.LocalidadId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_3446F2C567707C89");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.TipoIdentificacion)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Contacto)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.TipoIdentificacionId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_3446F2C565478DC6");
            });

             .

             .

             .

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

This is the **model**

```
namespace Lcore.Models
{
    public partial class Contacto
    {
        public Contacto()
        {
            EntidadFiscalContacto = new HashSet<EntidadFiscalContacto>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? NumeroIdentificacion { get; set; }
        public string Nombres { get; set; }
        public string Apellidos { get; set; }
        public DateTime? FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
        public short? Genero { get; set; }
        public int TipoIdentificacionId { get; set; }
        public int LocalidadId { get; set; }
        public int? ImagenId { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaCreado { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaEditado { get; set; }
        public string Nota { get; set; }
        public bool Activo { get; set; }

        public virtual ContactoImagen Imagen { get; set; }
        public virtual Localidad Localidad { get; set; }
        public virtual TipoIdentificacion TipoIdentificacion { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<EntidadFiscalContacto> EntidadFiscalContacto { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my services configuration in the **startup.cs** file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

             // other service configurations go here
            // replace "YourDbContext" with the class name of your DbContext
            services.AddDbContextPool<LCoreContext>(options => options
                // replace with your connection string
                .UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LCoreConnection"), mySqlOptions => mySqlOptions
                    // replace with your Server Version and Type
                    .ServerVersion(new Version(10, 3, 14), ServerType.MySql)
            ));
        }
```

Database connection error can not be since I could generate the models. And on the other hand I tried to create a controller without an associated model and I had no problems. This was the command I used.

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator  controller -name ContactosController  -dc LCoreContext -outDir Controllers -actions
```

Any help or hint that you can provide me, I will greatly appreciate.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm noticing that the command to scaffold the controller seems to be wrong. It should be `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator` and not `dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, yes at the beginning it was something that also caught my attention but dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator and dotnet aspnet-codegenerator work the same way. 
I'm going to edit it anyway to make it clearer.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message `Option 'data server' not supported.` tells you, that you are using an option named `data server` in your `LCoreConnection` connection string.

This option is not supported by Pomelo (see [MySQL .NET Connection String Options](https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/) for supported options).

If you have trouble finding the location, where you set this option, execute a solution-wide search for it.

Comment: It was exactly that, I can't believe I couldn't have seen such a simple mistake, a sign that I still have a lot to learn. Thank you very much for the reply. and sorry for the delay.